# Linking to framework with cmake on Mac OS X

Tags: c++, linker, ogre3d

I'm attempting to link a program against ogre and a few other libraries  on OS X using cmake, but I keep getting this error:

```
ld: warning: directory '/Library/Frameworks/SDL.framework/Debug' following -L not found
ld: warning: directory '-framework Cocoa/Debug' following -L not found
ld: warning: directory '-framework Cocoa' following -L not found
ld: warning: directory '/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenAL.framework/Debug' following -L not found
ld: warning: directory '/Library/Frameworks/Ogre.framework/Debug' following -L not found
ld: warning: directory '/opt/local/lib/libogg.dylib/Debug' following -L not found
ld: warning: path '/opt/local/lib/libogg.dylib' following -L not a directory
ld: warning: directory '/Users/hydrowolfy/Documents/newphysgame/physgame/physgameengine/data/macosx/ogre/Debug' following -L not found
ld: warning: directory '/Users/hydrowolfy/Documents/newphysgame/physgame/physgameengine/data/macosx/ogre' following -L not found
ld: warning: directory '/Users/hydrowolfy/Documents/newphysgame/physgame/physgameengine/data/macosx/openal/Debug' following -L not found
ld: warning: directory '/Users/hydrowolfy/Documents/newphysgame/physgame/physgameengine/data/macosx/openal' following -L not found
ld: warning: directory '/Users/hydrowolfy/Documents/newphysgame/physgame/physgameengine/data/macosx/oggvorbis/Debug' following -L not found
ld: warning: directory '/Users/hydrowolfy/Documents/newphysgame/physgame/physgameengine/data/macosx/oggvorbis' following -L not found
ld: library not found for -lOgreMain
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Command /Developer/usr/bin/g++-4.2 failed with exit code 1
```

The same cmake files work on windows and Linux. I'm trying to link against the ogre 1.7.2 framework that I got from the SDK on ogre's site. I think this is a linking issue, not an ogre issue though. Linking against frameworks with cmake is not as intuitive as I had hoped. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: It's likely an error in your CMake script. Do you mind posting it?

Comment: Thanks for your response, and sorry for the delay. I had to help a teammate get this merged cleanly, but everything in the original post still applies. Here is the root CMakeLists.txt: http://gitorious.org/physgame/physgame/blobs/master/CMakeLists.txt Here is the one we expect the problems to be in: http://gitorious.org/physgame/physgame/blobs/master/physgameengine/CMakeLists.txt

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, you should [note](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_Useful_Variables#System_.26_Compiler_Information) that `${APPLE}` "does not imply that the system is Mac OS X, only that **APPLE** is #defined in C/C++ header files." Use `IF(${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME} MATCHES "Darwin")` to check for OS X.

I don't have your build environment to test the following suggestions, but give them a try:

Line [309](http://gitorious.org/physgame/physgame/blobs/4961b66da984e9245129bea94e3b8048d42d6375/physgameengine/CMakeLists.txt#line309) and [321](http://gitorious.org/physgame/physgame/blobs/4961b66da984e9245129bea94e3b8048d42d6375/physgameengine/CMakeLists.txt#line321) have a typo. It should be `"${OGRE_INCLUDE_DIR}"` (not `${OGRE_INCLUDE_DIRS}`).

At [line 327](http://gitorious.org/physgame/physgame/blobs/4961b66da984e9245129bea94e3b8048d42d6375/physgameengine/CMakeLists.txt#line327), `${SDL_LIBRARY}`, `${OPENAL_LIBRARY}`, and `${OGG_LIBRARY}` are paths to the library *files* when they should be the paths to the *directories* of those libraries. `link_directories` tells the linker which directories contain the libraries that you specify in `target_link_libraries`.

Other than OGRE, [line 327](http://gitorious.org/physgame/physgame/blobs/4961b66da984e9245129bea94e3b8048d42d6375/physgameengine/CMakeLists.txt#line327) specifies libraries (SDL, AL, and OGG) whose `FindXXX.cmake` doesn't define a `_LIB_DIR` variable (or equivalent that indicates the directory containing the library). So, that line should be

```
link_directories("${OGRE_LIB_DIR}")
```

Also, [line 336](http://gitorious.org/physgame/physgame/blobs/4961b66da984e9245129bea94e3b8048d42d6375/physgameengine/CMakeLists.txt#line336) does not seem to be correct syntax. [`target_link_libraries`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake-2-8-docs.html#command%3atarget_link_libraries) takes the target (which should be the physgame library in this case) as the first argument, but you've passed it the path to the directory of the Ogre library. Since you can't call that command until you define the target, you'll have to defer it to [line 386](http://gitorious.org/physgame/physgame/blobs/4961b66da984e9245129bea94e3b8048d42d6375/physgameengine/CMakeLists.txt#line386).

Change [line 386](http://gitorious.org/physgame/physgame/blobs/4961b66da984e9245129bea94e3b8048d42d6375/physgameengine/CMakeLists.txt#line386) from:

```
target_link_libraries( ${PROJECT_NAME} OgreMain ${Bullet_LibraryNames} cAudio SDL )
```

to:

```
target_link_libraries(
    ${PROJECT_NAME}
    "${OGRE_LIBRARIES}"
    ${Bullet_LibraryNames}
    "${OPENAL_LIBRARY}" 
    "${SDL_LIBRARY}"
)
```

You might also be interested in: http://www.ogre3d.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=58610&start=0